# How to make string formatting mechanism in Java?

Tags: java, tokenize

I'm trying to make a string formatting mechanism, which pretty much looks like the [Winamp Advanced Title Formatting](http://media.winamp.com/main/help/50/atf/atf.htm).

I have some 'variables' (or metadata fields) bound to object properties, in the form *%varname%*. So, for example, the *%title%* metadata field is bound to a song title, say 'Conquest of Paradise', the *%artist%* metadata field is bound to the song artist, say 'Vangelis', and the *%feat%* metadata field is bound to the featuring artists, say 'English Chamber Choir'.

Now I want to display the song depending on a given formatting, for example:

```
%title%[ (by %artist%[ featuring %feat%])]
```

Square brackets mean *don't display unless (all) metadata inside the brackets were set*. Nesting of square brackets should be possible.
So abovementioned formatting string says: display the metadata field *%title%* and, if *%artist%* is set (not an empty string), display `(by %artist%)`, but if the *%feat%* metadata field is also non-empty, then display that field also. In the abovementioned example, it would become:

> Conquest of Paradise (by Vangelis featuring English Chamber Choir)

Now how do I make such mechanism? Where do I start?

I guess that I have to tokenize the string and then per 'section' search for metadata tags?

Comment: So what you are really looking for is tokenizing, not formatting? For formatting read the Javadoc for `String.format()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build up a tree structure that represents the pattern.  For your example, it would look like:

```
root
 + variable (title)
 + group 
   + text (" (by ")
   + variable (artist)
   + group
     + text (" featuring ")
     + variable (feat)
   + text (")")
```

Then when you evaluate meta data against your tree, you store at the group level whether all variables and sub-groups in the group evaluated, and if so use the text.

Your tree classes would look something like:

```
interface Node { String evaluate(Map<String, String> metaData); }

class Group implements Node 
{
  private final List<Node> _children;

  Group(final List<Node> children) { _children = children; }

  @Override
  public String evaluate(final Map<String, String> metaData)
  {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (final Node node : _children)
    {
      final String subText = node.evaluate(metaData);
      if (subText == null)
        return null;
      sb.append(subText);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}

class Text implements Node 
{
  private final String _text;

  Text(final String text) { _text = text; }

  @Override
  public String evaluate(final Map<String, String> metaData)
  {
    return _text;
  }
}

class Variable implements Node 
{
  private final String _variable;

  Variable(final String variable) { _variable = variable; }

  @Override
  public String evaluate(final Map<String, String> metaData)
  {
    return metaData.get(_variable);
  }
}
```

All that's left to do is to work out how to parse your string to create the tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827593/how-to-make-string-formatting-mechanism-in-java/15827798#15827798) of [SimonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445901/simonc), I've written a tokenizer what executes what has been suggested, to split the formatting string into tokens.

```
public class Main {

    private static void buildTree(String format) {
        Stack<Token> st = new Stack<>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        GroupToken root = new GroupToken();
        st.push(root);

        boolean var = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < format.length(); i++) {
            char currentChar = format.charAt(i);
            switch (currentChar) {
                case '[':
                    String str = sb.toString();
                    sb.setLength(0); // Flush the StringBuilder
                    if (!str.equals("")) {
                        ((GroupToken) st.peek()).add(new TextToken(str));
                    }
                    GroupToken gt = new GroupToken();
                    ((GroupToken) st.peek()).add(gt);
                    st.push(gt);
                    break;
                case ']':
                    str = sb.toString();
                    sb.setLength(0); // Flush the StringBuilder
                    if (!str.equals("")) {
                        ((GroupToken) st.peek()).add(new TextToken(str));
                    }
                    st.pop();
                    break;
                case '%':
                    var = !var;
                    if (var) {
                        str = sb.toString();
                        sb.setLength(0); // Flush the StringBuilder
                        if (!str.equals("")) {
                            ((GroupToken) st.peek()).add(new TextToken(str));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        str = sb.toString();
                        sb.setLength(0); // Flush the StringBuilder
                        ((GroupToken) st.peek()).add(new VariableToken(str));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    sb.append(currentChar);
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Process the last remains of the string buffer...
        String str = sb.toString();
        sb.setLength(0); // Flush the StringBuilder
        if (!str.equals("")) {
            ((GroupToken) st.peek()).add(new TextToken(str));
        }
        st.pop();
        System.out.println(root);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        buildTree("%title%[ (%alttitle%[, #%track%])]");
    }

}

abstract class Token {

    public abstract String toString(int indent);

}

class TextToken extends Token {

    private String text;

    public TextToken(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString(0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(int indent) {
        return "TextToken[\"" + this.text + "\"]\n";
    }
}

class VariableToken extends Token {

    private String text;

    public VariableToken(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString(0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(int indent) {
        return "VariableToken[\"" + this.text + "\"]\n";
    }
}

class GroupToken extends Token {

    ArrayList<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

    public GroupToken() { }

    public void add(Token token) {
        this.tokens.add(token);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString(0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(int indent) {
        String out = "GroupToken[\n";
        for (Token t : this.tokens) {
            out += StringUtils.pad("", 4 * (indent + 1), ' ') + t.toString(indent + 1);
        }
        out += StringUtils.pad("", 4 * indent, ' ') + "]\n";
        return out;
    }

}
```